# How to Download files from SFTP location to Google Storage bucket using Python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have 6 files in SFTP location and want to download them on a daily basis and upload them to Google cloud bucket.

I tried downloading files to the local computer and uploading to GCP and when trying to download the same directly from SFTP location GCP bucket it's not working

Comment: Please share with us the steps that you already tried and the error

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) and this [one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)

but as @ChristianGonzalez mentioned please provided more info on what did you tried before and/or what error(s) did you encounter.